# Communication between fragments via interfaces

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, bottomnavigationview

The fragments are a part of the bottom navigation bar, so far so good on the navigation part. But when i try to pass data from fragment1 to fragment2 the app is crashing. Also I am using the example given by google at this following [link](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

When I use the following code android studio gives me deprecated warning!

```
@Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
```

So I am using ***CONTEXT*** instead of ***ACTIVITY*** below is my code that crashes :

MainActivity

```
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.br.tron.bottombar.RadioFragment;
import com.br.tron.bottombar.StreamFragment;
import com.br.tron.bottombar.InfoFragment;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RadioFragment.OnNameSetListener {

    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;
    private Fragment fragment;
    private FragmentManager fragmentManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragment = new RadioFragment();
        final FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.main_container, fragment).commit();

        bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationBar);
        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.nav_button_one:
                        fragment = new RadioFragment();
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_button_two:
                        fragment = new StreamFragment();
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_button_three:
                        fragment = new InfoFragment();
                        break;
                }
                final FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.main_container, fragment).commit();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    public void performStreamClick(){
        View view = bottomNavigationView.findViewById(R.id.nav_button_two);
        view.performClick();
    }

    @Override
    public void setUrl(String url) {
        StreamFragment frag=(StreamFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("frag");
        frag.getUrl(url);
    }
}
```

RadioFragment(Fragment1 where the data exist)

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

public class RadioFragment extends Fragment implements Button.OnClickListener  {

    Button buttonman;
    View rootView;
    String url;
    Activity a;
    OnNameSetListener onNameSetListener;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof Activity) {
            a = (Activity) context;
            try{
                onNameSetListener=(OnNameSetListener) context;
            }
            catch (Exception e){}
        }
    }

    public RadioFragment(){
    };

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_player, container, false);
        buttonman = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonman);
        buttonman.setOnClickListener(this);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        /*Fragment fragment = new StreamFragment();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();*/
        url="www.idontknow.com";
        onNameSetListener.setUrl(url);
        ((MainActivity)a).performStreamClick();
    }

    public interface OnNameSetListener
    {
        public void setUrl(String url);
    }
}
```

StreamFragment(*fragment2* where I want to send the data -from *fragment1*)

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class StreamFragment extends Fragment {

    TextView textViewStream;

    public StreamFragment(){};

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater,final ViewGroup container,final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_stream, container, false);

    }

    public void getUrl(String url)
    {
        textViewStream.setText(url);
    }

}
```

**LOGCAT**

> 01-06 20:10:23.023 3744-3744/com.br.tron.bottombar E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                        Process: com.br.tron.bottombar, PID: 3744
>                                                                        java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.br.tron.bottombar.StreamFragment.getUrl(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
>                                                                            at com.br.tron.bottombar.MainActivity.setUrl(MainActivity.java:64)
>                                                                            at com.br.tron.bottombar.RadioFragment.onClick(RadioFragment.java:61)
>                                                                            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5201)
>                                                                            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21209)
>                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5525)
>                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
>                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
>   01-06 20:10:24.663 3744-3744/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 3744 SIG: 9

Answer (score 3):

You never register the `frag` tag you later search for.

In your MainActivity modify:

```
final FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
transaction.add(R.id.main_container, fragment, "frag").commit();
...
final FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.main_container, fragment, "frag").commit();
...
```

In addition to that within your StreamFragment class you never set the TextViewStream variable after you inflate your layout.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater,final ViewGroup container,final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_stream, container, false);
    textViewStream = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ID_GOES_HERE);
    return view;
}
```

**Edit: Further Errors**

You're getting a `ClassCastException` because you're not checking to see whether the fragment you get in `MainActivity.setUrl` is a `StreamFragment`. And it makes sense that it's failing because you register the `frag` tag for all three types of custom Fragments. Here's a further solution:

```
        fragment = new RadioFragment();
        final FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.main_container, fragment, "radio_fragment").commit();
        ...

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                String tag = "";
                case R.id.nav_button_one:
                    fragment = new RadioFragment();
                    tag = "radio_fragment";
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_button_two:
                    fragment = new StreamFragment();
                    tag = "stream_fragment";
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_button_three:
                    fragment = new InfoFragment();
                    tag = "info_fragment";
                    break;
            }
            final FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.main_container, fragment, tag).commit();
            return true;
        }
```

Make the appropriate change in the Tag string in `setUrl`:

```
StreamFragment frag=(StreamFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("stream_fragment");
if (frag != null) frag.getUrl(url);
```

Comment: still crashing mate I have initialized the textViewStream as siva already pointed that out and modified the MainActivity according to your suggestion

Comment: @user3599100 Is the stacktrace still the same? Could you please post the new stacktrace.

Comment: New Stack trace - > java.lang.ClassCastException: RadioFragment cannot be cast to StreamFragment 

Roughly this code is pointed to -> ` @Override
    public void setUrl(String url) {
        StreamFragment frag=(StreamFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("frag");
        frag.getUrl(url);
    }`

Comment: you code seems to handle the class cast exception but the interface is still not able to transfer the data i.e. the URL from frag1 to frag2

Comment: on debugging the application I found out that string frag is always returning NULL :(

Comment: @user3599100 Right, because we're no longer using the `frag` string. You need to use either `radio_fragment`, `stream_fragment`, or `info_fragment`. Specifically in the `setUrl` method you need to be using `stream_fragment`.

Comment: could please update the answer with your current suggestion, didn't quite get you !

Comment: @user3599100  Have your replaced `"frag"` with `"stream_fragment"` in `findFragmentByTag()`?

Comment: @Gary99 Yeah gives me NULL

Answer (score 1):

Both of the current answers key in on your crash problem.  I expect that will take care of your primary question.  @asadmshah seems to have taken care of your next problem.  Make sure to up vote his answer & accept it.

Regarding the warning from using Google's example code, here is what AS will currently give you if you tell it to create a new fragment.

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}
```

The point of this is to make sure that the Activity you're attaching to implements the interface you've defined in your fragment.

And on the subject of the interface, all fragment to activity comms should be done through it.  It would be better to find a way to call `performStreamClick()` through the interface as well.  (I just realized I made this same mistake on an app I started several months ago but am just finishing up now :).

Lastly, just an FYI, you can get the attached activity of a fragment with `getActivity()`.

EDIT:
1st, it might help to see your current code.  I'm going to assume you have what Asad has put in his answer, more or less.  Also, what is the expected behavior?  I believe that you make a selection in `RadioFragment` then replace it with `StreamFragment`.  That is, both fragments take the whole nav bar, they don't exist at the same time.  If this is wrong, let me know.

If you're still calling `setUrl()` and `performStreamClick()` in the same order as before, you're getting null because you've never created a fragment by that name.  You can't find a fragment you haven't already created.

Without actually setting this up to test it myself, I believe what you need to do would be to save the url in a global variable in `setUrl()`, then in your click listener, pass that to the `StreamFragment` when you create it.

See the "Deliver a Message to a Fragment" section of the link you've sited for doing that

```
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ArticleFragment.ARG_POSITION, position);
        newFragment.setArguments(args);
```

(obviously, handling your url string instead of the int in the example)

Also, it's not a bad idea to handle null when searching for a fragment that should exist already

```
    StreamFragment frag=(StreamFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("stream_frag");
    if(frag == null) {
        final FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        StreamFragment fragment = new StreamFragment();
        transaction.replace(R.id.main_container, fragment, "stream_frag").commit();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks man I was able to achieve what you said through Interface instead of creating a new Activity.. you saved me some memory :) I don't have enough points or would have up voted you

Comment: Glad to help.  Only about 1 1/2 years in to Android & still learning a lot myself.  If Asad doesn't get back to you on your last question, let me know & I'll try to help.

Comment: you could help me too.. the question is still unanswered ! I am not able to send the data to target fragment :(

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize your `textViewStream` in the `StreamFragment` fragment.

Comment: Where should I initialize oncreate or inside getUrl ? which is better ?

Comment: Please add some more information to you answer. Perhaps explain why this solution should work and why the OP's way doesn't.